# jQuery dataTables and selecting a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get a [jQuery dataTable](http://datatables.net) to behave in such a way that a user can select a row and then click a button (located elsewhere on the page, but *not* on the table or in it) and have a JS alert pop up.

Here is my dataTable:

```
$("#my-datatable").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing" : true,
    // Commenting out next line
    //"sDom" : 't',
    "sAjaxSource" : "some/url/on/my/server",
    "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        aoData.push({
            "name" : "asking",
            "value" : "yes"
        });

        request = $.ajax({
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : fnCallback
        });
    },

    "aoColumns" : [
        {
            "mDataProp" : "name"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp" : "expr"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp" : "seq"
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is my button:

```
<div id="bam-btn-div">
    <input type="button" id="bam-btn" value="BAM!" onclick="bam();"/>
</div>
```

When the user selects a row in the dataTable, and then clicks the button, I want the following function called:

```
function bam() {
    alert("Deleting the selected row");

    // Delete the selected row in the dataTable
}
```

Finally, the HTML table that the jQuery dataTable is attempting to populate:

```
<div id="datatable-div">
    <table id="optconfig-datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Expression</th>
                <th>Sequence</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to follow the example [here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) but couldn't get anything to work. Can anybody spot what configurations I need to add (to the dataTable and/or otherwise)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are using jQuery, you might as well stay on track.

```
$('#bam-btn').on('click', function(){
    alert("BAM!");
});
```

On a side note, ID's must be unique, but I'm sure you know that, so make sure you're not trying to re-use the same ID over and over.

Moreover, if this element is added into the DOM after `.ready()` execution, you'll need to attach the event handler to a static parent element so it may delegate the click event properly.

```
$(document).on('click', '#bam-btn', function(){
    alert("BAM");
});
```

**I'll leave the above in place, I don't like to delete entire portions of my answer as you never know who may find it helpful in the future**

First, we need to create a variable that's available to all scopes of all functions. This way, we can reference the variable to get a hold of the element we want to remove.

*We should place this variable **outside** of the document ready function*

```
var theRow = '';
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //existing code here
});
```

Now that we have a 'global scope' variable prepared, we can modify it and access it anytime.

```
var theRow = '';
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('tr').click(function(){
        //we need to store a unique piece of information about this row.
        //Without much to go on, I'm going to rely on the index.
        theRow = $(this).index();
    });

    $('#bam-btn').click(function(){
       $('tr').eq(theRow).remove(); 
    });
});​
```

[And here is your *decent* working jsFiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/B9BW8/)

**For future users, and anyone else whom may find this useful**

The `:eq()` selector provided by jQuery **cannot** leverage `.querySelectorAll()` to gain a decently large performance boost. Because of this, and for the time being, you should always use `.eq()` over `:eq()`.

Comment: (+1) - very sorry please see my edited Javascript - I actually want to delete the selected row, not just display the alert. This was my oversight.

Comment: Sure, no problem. We just need to delegate a click function to the rows. Once we do, we can then properly remove the row from the DOM. Can you show me the generated markup for a single row? I'll be happy to help then.

Comment: @pnongrata Please see the update to my answer with the attached jsFiddle. This should work out of the box, however; you may have to make some changes to the selectors I've chosen as they're ambiguous.

Comment: Just added the HTML table - hope that's what you were looking for, and thanks again for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that your:

```
function bam() {
    alert("BAM!");
}
```

Is not in this statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // STATEMENT
});
```

If your function is in the `$(document).ready()`, that means it's available only in that scope, in that particular `function()`.

Move your code above or below the `$(document).ready()` statement, and your `onclick` event handler in your button will be able to **find it and invoke** it.

To delete a specific element from your data-table, try with this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $("#my-datatable").dataTable( {
        "bProcessing" : true,
        // Commenting out next line
        //"sDom" : 't',
        "sAjaxSource" : "some/url/on/my/server",
        "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "asking",
                "value" : "yes"
            });

            request = $.ajax({
                "dataType" : "json",
                "type" : "GET",
                "url" : sSource,
                "data" : aoData,
                "success" : fnCallback
            });
        },

        "aoColumns" : [
            {
                "mDataProp" : "name"
            },
            {
                "mDataProp" : "expr"
            },
            {
                "mDataProp" : "seq"
            }
        ]
    });$("#my-datatable").dataTable( {
        "bProcessing" : true,
        // Commenting out next line
        //"sDom" : 't',
        "sAjaxSource" : "some/url/on/my/server",
        "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "asking",
                "value" : "yes"
            });

            request = $.ajax({
                "dataType" : "json",
                "type" : "GET",
                "url" : sSource,
                "data" : aoData,
                "success" : fnCallback
            });
        },

        "aoColumns" : [
            {
                "mDataProp" : "name"
            },
            {
                "mDataProp" : "expr"
            },
            {
                "mDataProp" : "seq"
            }
        ]
    });

    $('button#bam-btn').on('click', function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
    } );
});
```

Comment: (+1) - very sorry please see my edited Javascript - I actually want to delete the selected row, not just display the alert. This was my oversight.

Comment: @pnongrata I've updated my answer. Please check if that works for you, and accept my answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: I think that your method is probably better. I'm not leveraging the dataTables functions to perform my actions. This may or may not have performance implications, but I always try to stay within the API I'm using as much as possible. +1, and if this works for OP, he should accept it over mine.

Comment: :) I've used dataTables 2-3 years ago, and I remember when I was dealing with similar issues :) if you ask me, plugin has disadvantages when it comes to accessing some properties and methods related to the plugin, as you can see from my delete solution :) KUTGW!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a table with dynamic data load. Every time I was adding contents, the old nodes disappear, losing the events linked. 
I solved the problem invoking a function after the data load:

```
    function insertevents(table_id){
        var oTable = jQuery('#'+tableid).dataTable( {"bRetrieve": true });
        oTable.$('tr').click(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
        } );
        // Extra code here
    }
```

It's important to add the "bRetrieve" parameter because the table was previously initialized.

Also, I've improved the functionality controlling keyboard events for accessibility:

```
        oTable.$('tr').keyup( function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 32) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
            }       
        } ); 
        oTable.$('tr').keydown( function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 32) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Desactivamos este efecto
            }
        });
```

This bunch of lines should replace the comment line of the first example. Now the table can be used from the keyboard, selecting with intro or space key. Remember to add a tabindex=0 to the elements inserted in the table, so we can navigate with the tab key.

Answer (score 0):

http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/index.html

This is similar to what you want.